# Inequality based conditional cumulative sum in R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have been trying to do code this:
For each

[image: equation?]

So far, the best way I came up to do this is by using a loop.Here is an example

```
y=rnorm(10)
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4)
z=c(5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9)
data=data.frame(y,x,z)
n=10

s=rep(NA,length(unique(x))*length(unique(z)))
dim(s)=c(length(unique(x)),length(unique(z)))
for (i in 1:length(unique(x))){
  for (j in 1:length(unique(z))){
       s[i,j]=sum(y*as.numeric((x<=unique(x)[i]))*
                    as.numeric((z<=unique(z)[j])))
}
}
```

The output is OK like this, but when my dimensions grows, this becomes inefficient.
Since, for a given z, this looks like a conditional cumulative sum,  I am 100% sure that there is a more efficient way of doing this, without the loop.

Would any of you have any suggestion? If I didn't have z, I know I could use data.table:

```
 s=data[order(x)][,lapply(.SD, sum),by=c("x"), .SDcols=c("y")]
  s=s[,lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols=c("y")]
```

but with more than one index (x and z, not just x) I was not able to formulate the program.

Comment: THis would be easier to understand if you show a small sample of inout data and the desired output.

Comment: Agreed. I am doing this right now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you require `data.table` for this, as you're using the whole of "y" for each group. This'll be easier to accomplish through some linear algebra:

```
t(y*outer(x, unique(x), '<=')) %*% outer(z, unique(z), '<=')
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.3538152  0.1762013  0.1762013  0.1762013  0.1762013
[2,] 0.3538152 -0.7308157 -1.2421102 -1.2421102 -1.2421102
[3,] 0.3538152 -0.7308157 -1.2421102 -1.1770919 -1.8315592
[4,] 0.3538152 -0.7308157 -1.2421102 -1.1770919 -4.1171477
```

---

Here's your version of code for 3-dimensions:

```
set.seed(1)
y=rnorm(10)
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4)
z=c(5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9)
w=c(7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11)
n=10

s=rep(NA,length(unique(w))*length(unique(z))*length(unique(x)))
dim(s)=c(length(unique(w)),length(unique(z)), length(unique(x)))
for (i in 1:length(unique(w))) {
  for (j in 1:length(unique(z))) {
    for (k in 1:length(unique(x))) {
       s[i,j, k]=sum(y*as.numeric((w<=unique(w)[i]))*
                    as.numeric((z<=unique(z)[j]))*
                    as.numeric((x<=unique(x)[k])))
    }
  }
}
```

Here's how you can accomplish this with the same idea as my previous answer:

```
t1 <- outer(x, unique(x), '<=')
t2 <- outer(z, unique(z), '<=')
t3 <- outer(w, unique(w), '<=')
lapply(seq_along(unique(x)), function(idx) t(y*t1[,idx]*t2) %*% t3)
```

Here the output is a list (instead of array), but the output is identical, you may compare the results with "s". You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: What if I add other indexes, say 4 more? That's why I tend to prefer using data.table, no?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you're using the whole of "y" for each i,j. But data.table's .SD will only provide the values of "y" for the group in "by". I don't know how one would do that. Extending this to 4-more indices is straightforward using the current method I think.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example how would you extend this for 3 dimensions, instead of 2? Because this would require using arrays (3 dimensions), and not standard matrices (2 dimensions).

Thanks a lot

Comment: @user17645, hope this edit helps. You can extend this to your data dimensions.

Comment: @user17645 given that this seems to solve your problem, efficiently, is extensible to n-dimensions (which was not part of the OP - until you edited it - you are lucky Arun has unlimited patience!) I hope you will accept the answer by pressing the green tick mark to show your appreciation for all the effort that's gone into this for you?

Comment: I might be stupid or something related, but when I try to do it for 4 dimensions, using the approach:


`lapply(list(idx=seq_along(unique(x)),idr=seq_along(unique(r))), function(idx,idr) t(y*t1[,idx]*t2) %*% (t3*t4[,idr])`

I don't manage to get anything... I am quite new to R so I am having difficulties to these basic steps...

Would @Arun help me again? 

Thanks

Comment: You should *uncheck this answer* so that others can take a look at it. Maybe there's a better way that has eluded me. I'm sorry I can't invest more time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @arun! It helped me. Now I need to find a way to write the lapply function. But I definetly got the idea. Maybe using mapply helps

Answer (score 0):

Following @Arun argumets, I managed to nest two lapply functions to get the solution generalized to upper dimensions.

```
lapply(seq_along(unique(x)), function(idx){lapply(seq_along(unique(r)),
                                              function(idr) t(y*t1[,idx]*t2)%*%(t3
                                              *t4[,idr]))})
```

For adding other dimensions, I will keep nesting lapply functions. Is there a cleaner way to do this?